# How to estimate a Vector Autoregression model using ARCH estimation (VAR-GARCH)?

Tags: time-series, estimation, garch, vector-autoregression

I estimated a vector autoregression (VAR) model using 3 lags and 5 variables. However, when I estimated the equation using OLS, heteroskedasticity was present. In this sort of a situation, what is the procedure to solve the heteroskedasticity issue?

Can I use ARCH to estimate the VAR equation in the following manner? Including GARCH(1), makes the ARCH coefficient negative. So I decided only to include an ARCH(1). What is the procedure I should follow to estimate a VAR using GARCH/ARCH method?

Comment: Are you asking about software implementation (which would be off-topic) or the conceptual soundness of a VAR-ARCH model? Consider editing your post to clarify.

Comment: @RichardHardy I'm referring to the conceptual soundness of a VAR-ARCH model. I edited the post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your software has the functionality, you can estimate the VAR-ARCH model jointly, and that will be the efficient way of doing that. Otherwise, you estimate the VAR part first and then estimate ARCH on the residuals from the VAR. In the latter case both VAR and ARCH estimates are inefficient, but at least they are consistent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. "Estimate the Var part first and then estimate ARCH on the residuals from the VAR", I couldn't understand this step.  Can the VAR-ARCH model be estimated jointly in R?

Comment: @Geek_Tech, `rmgarch` package in R has the functionality to estimate VAR-GARCH, but I am not sure if the estimation is simultaneous or sequential. It should be possible to find this out from the vignette or the help files for the particular functions from the package. (If you do, I would appreciate if you let me know, too. Thanks.)

Comment: Sure, I will look into that and let you know. Thanks again.